# sections of a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

I am reading Griffiths and Harris book Principles of Algebraic geometry.

Let $L\rightarrow M$ be a holomorphic line bundle, with trivializations $\varphi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\rightarrow U_\alpha\times \mathbb{C}$ over an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $M$ and transition functions $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$ relative to $\{\varphi_\alpha\}$.

Given this set up, It says the following:

> Any section of $L$ over $U\subseteq M$ is given exactly by a collection if functions $s_\alpha\in\mathcal{O}(U\cap U_\alpha)$ satisfying $s_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$ in $U\cap U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

Just for simplicity, I would like to consider particular case :

> Any section of $L$ over $M$ is given exactly by a collection of functions $s_\alpha\in\mathcal{O}(U_\alpha)$ satisfying $s_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$ in $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

Given $\varphi_\alpha:\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\rightarrow U_\alpha\times \mathbb{C}$ we have a section $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow L$ given by $\sigma_\alpha(u)=\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(u,1)$. One would hope to glue these sections $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow L$ to get a section $\sigma:M\rightarrow L$. But the problem is there is no reason why would $\sigma_\alpha(x)=\sigma_\beta(x)$ for $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$. So, we should look for another collection of sections on $U_\alpha$ that we can glue.

We have $s_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. This would give another section $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow L$ with $u\mapsto s_\alpha(u)\sigma_\alpha(u)$.

Now, the condition $g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta=s_\alpha$ gives some hope to glue these sections $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$. Only thing we need to prove is that $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha=s_\beta\sigma_\beta$ on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ i.e., $s_\alpha(u)\sigma_\alpha(u)=s_\beta(u)\sigma_\beta(u)$ for each $u\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297389/connection-on-a-principal-bundle-and-transition-functions-as-in-hitchins-notes/297409?noredirect=1#comment740855_297409 says that $\sigma_\beta=g_{\alpha\beta}\sigma_\alpha$.

We have $s_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$, which imply $\sigma_\alpha s_\alpha=\sigma_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$ which imply that $\sigma_\alpha s_\alpha=\sigma_\beta s_\beta$ as $\sigma_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}=\sigma_\beta$. Thus, we can glue sections $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$ to get a section $\sigma:M\rightarrow L$ such that $\sigma|_{U_\alpha}=s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$.

Given a section $s:M\rightarrow L$ I want to construct $s_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $s_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$.

We already have sections $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow L$. Let $x\in U_\alpha$ then, we have $s(x)\in \pi^{-1}(x)$ and $\sigma_\alpha(x)\in \pi^{-1}(x)$. As $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is $1$ dimensional, there exists $a\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $s(x)=a\sigma_\alpha(x)$ and this $a$ is what I plan to declare as $s_\alpha(x)$. This gives $s_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. It remains to see why would $s_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$ on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

For $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$, I have $s(x)=s_\alpha(x)\sigma_\alpha(x)$ and $s(x)=s_\beta(x)\sigma_\beta(x)$. This is same as saying $s_\alpha(x)\sigma_\alpha(x)=s_\beta(x)\sigma_\beta(x)$. As $\sigma_\beta=\sigma_\alpha g_{\alpha\beta}$ we have $s_\alpha(x)\sigma_\alpha(x)=s_\beta(x)\sigma_\beta(x)
=s_\beta(x)\sigma_\alpha(x)g_{\alpha\beta}(x)$ i.e., we have 
$$s_\alpha(x)\sigma_\alpha(x)=s_\beta(x)g_{\alpha\beta}(x)\sigma_\alpha(x).$$
As  $\sigma_\alpha(x)\neq 0\in \pi^{-1}(x)$ this would mean $s_\alpha(x)=s_\beta(x)g_{\alpha\beta}(x)$ i.e., $s_\alpha=s_\beta g_{\alpha\beta}$.

As $\psi_\alpha^{-1}(x,0)=0$ and $\psi_\alpha^{-1}$ is bijection, we can not have $\sigma_\alpha(x)=\psi^{-1}(x,0)$ equal to $0$.

Can some one please confirm if this is correct or are there any gaps.

Comment: I do not see what you mean by $s_{\alpha}\sigma_{\alpha}$. My reasoning is the following: $\sigma_{\alpha}\colon U_{\alpha} \rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is a local section of your bundle. Since you have a diffeomorphism $\phi_{\alpha}$ you may write $\phi_{\alpha}(\sigma_{\alpha}(x)) = (x,s_{\alpha}(x))$. You can act on $s_{\alpha}$ with $g_{\beta \alpha}$ getting a new $\sigma'_{\beta}$ on $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}$. If this coincide with $\sigma_{\beta}$ (recall you fixed a family $(U_{\alpha},\sigma_{\alpha})$), then you can glue all of them finding a unique $\sigma$.

Comment: by $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$ I mean the function $u\mapsto s_\alpha(u)\sigma_\alpha(u)$. As $s_\alpha(u)$ is a complex number, $s_\alpha(u)\sigma_\alpha(u)$ belongs to same fiber as $\sigma_\alpha(u)$. Is this alright? @Gibbs

Comment: Ok, but I do not see why you need it.

Comment: I have said that already. As $\sigma_\alpha$ has less hope of gluing together, I have considered $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$ hoping that they glue together and I am almost close. You can see where I got stuck @Gibbs

Comment: What do you mean by 'less hope'? The statement you are considering is saying that if you have a family of functions $s_{\alpha}\colon U_{\alpha} \cap U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $s_{\beta} = g_{\beta \alpha}s_{\alpha}$ on $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta} \cap U$, then you can construct a unique local section of $L$ over $U$ (because $\mathcal{O}$ is a sheaf). I was trying to explain this in my first comment (assume that my $U_{\alpha}$s are an open covering of $U$ in the comment above).

Comment: I have sections $\sigma_\alpha:U_\alpha\rightarrow L$. I was trying to produce a section $M\rightarrow L$ just from this, but, there is less hope for this sections to glue i.e., there is no reason why $\sigma_\alpha(x)=\sigma_\beta(x)$ for $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$... This is what  I mean by less hope.. So, I have to look for another collection of sections on $U_\alpha$ that can glue.. That is why  I considered sections $s_\alpha\sigma_\alpha$.. Is this reasonable way to approach?

Comment: @Gibbs I also do not really understand how you are using the word "sheaf"... there are sections $s_\alpha\in \mathcal{O}(U_\alpha)$.. Are you saying $s_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\beta$ on $U_{\alpha\beta}$ is same as saying sections(of the sheaf) $s_\alpha$ glue together to give a map $s:M\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$... This would then give a section say $\tau: M \rightarrow L$ ??

Comment: @Gibbs Can you tell me what does it mean to say unitary line bundle?

Comment: I do not know that, I apologise. Anyway, I moved the discussion of yesterday to chat, it was getting too long.

Comment: @Gibbs can you give link to that chat?

Comment: I get access to the chat when replying your comments. Anyway, just a thought/guess: 'unitary' might refer to the presence of a unitary connection on the line bundle. I hope someone else can shed some light on this.